# Mouse.SetPosition() assigned variable is considered void

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to set the mouse position equal to the variable "location" but I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.MouseState". As far as I can tell "location" isn't void. Here is the code, which is a little cluttered due to trying to make this work:

```
class Player
{
    private Texture2D texture;
    private static int textureSize = 20;
    private static int screenWidth = Game1.Instance.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
    private static int screenHeight = Game1.Instance.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
    private static int halfTexture = (int)(textureSize * (screenHeight / (double)textureSize)) / 2;
    private Vector2 location;
    private Rectangle destination;
    private float speed;
    private MouseState mouse;

    public Player(Texture2D texture)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.location = new Vector2(screenWidth / 2 - halfTexture, screenHeight * 3 / 4 - halfTexture);
        this.destination = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, textureSize, textureSize);
        this.mouse = Mouse.SetPosition((int)location.X, (int)location.Y); // the error is here
    }
```

So what's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: what are values of `location.x` and `location.y` in this case?

Comment: X should be 390 and Y should be 440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the XNA documents I can still safely say that the `Mouse.SetPosition`-method returns `void` and you are trying to assign the return value of it to `this.mouse` which is of the type `MouseState`. Remove that assignment and you will be fine.

Comment: Oh! I get it. The "Mouse" class doesn't require an instance of it to set the position of the mouse.